# if ul with this class and style is display:none then add style left:-1px

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="dynamic" style="display: none;"></ul>
```

how can i use jQuery to do: if ul with this class and style is display:none then add style left:-1px

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this, as it would not show on the page anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try -

```
   $("ul.dynamic:hidden").css("left","-1px");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this (untested):

```
$('ul.dynamic').filter(':hidden').css({ left: "-1px" });
```

I split the selection on hidden elements in order to let jQuery use the native CSS selector for the first part of the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Use [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector

```
$("ul.dynamic:hidden").css('left', '-1px');
```